# Como instalar mi apk en el emulador Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

Quisiera saber como instalo mi apk en el emulador ***Genymotion***, ya sea por:

- Linea de comando usando el comando adb
- Metodo Drag and Drop (Si existe)

**Sistema operativo**: Windows 10

Gracias de ante mano por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por linea de comandos puedes realizarlo como lo harías en cualquier dispositivo por medio del Android Debug Bridge:

```
> adb install mi_aplicacion.apk
```

Otra opción es como comentas por medio de "Drag & Drop", agrega el .apk en el emulador `Genymotion` y automáticamente los instalara, importante comentar que esta opción funciona si tu .apk esta firmado.

Comment: Bueno firmare la apk, no sabia eso gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si desarrollas en **Android Studio** al abrir tu Dispositivo emulado lo reconoce y automáticamente se instalara.

Otra opción es compilar el apk desde la barra de herramientas y una ves generado el apk arrastrar al emulador, este reconocerá el apk y te dará la opción de instalarlo, debes activar "*fuentes desconocidas*" en el dispositivo para que se instale.

[image: build apk]

Comment: Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion híbrida, con ionic

Comment: Entonces obteniendo el apk, arrastrarlo al emulador pero antes activa la opción "fuentes desconocidas"

Comment: Gracias @Max Sandoval, voy a probar